# AOSP 14 - CTS Modules list & cases

Tags: android-source, cts, android-14

I need to fetch all the modules under which all the testcases associated. How & where do I get that I couldn't find it anywhere.

As per Releases notes:

> The number of test modules and test cases are as follows:
>
> 1. 1151 modules depending on the devices
> 2. 4.4M test cases over 2 ABIs
> 3. In Android 14, a total of 136 new modules are added and a total of 19 modules are removed. See the following tables for more information.

I'm trying to perform [CTS 14](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/cts/cts-14-release-notes) in a device it is going to bricked state or off. Is there any split I can do to run it like DrawElements and others kind of.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the CTS files on your Linux workmachine, you can use the CTS console command line to list the modules via the `list modules` command.

Ref: [CTS v2 console command reference](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/cts/command-console-v2#:%7E:text=Description-,list%20modules,-List%20all%20available)